# $\frac{d}{dx} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx$ is not $f(x)$ right?

Tags: calculus

It's 0, correct? Just to restate the question: by the fundamental theorem of calculus $\frac{d}{dx} \int_\infty^x f(x') dx' = f(x)$, but if the upper limit is not $x$ but $\infty$, the integrand is effectively a constant thus the $d/dx=0$.

Comment: Correct. I would use a different variable inside the integral in the title, similar to what you have in the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, exactly.
It is ambiguous to use the same variable for the differentiation and the integral sign. But the integral is not a function of $x$, therefore, a differentiation by $x$ is 0.